# Why do people assign $this = $(this) in many jQuery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I often see this as the first line of a plug-in:

```
$this = $(this);
```

Is this just for efficiency, to avoid getting the jQuery object each and every time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To cache the jQuery object and not have to instantiate it every time they require it.

Answer (score 2):

Just as the above answers says it will **cache the object** - sort of.

If you call `$(this)` jQuery will search in the DOM until it finds `this`-element. If you want to do alot of changes to the element, it will be faster to save the reference to `this`-element.

```
$this = $(this);
```

Now the element is saved as the `$this` variabel and if you want to do stuff to it again, you just use the variabel.

```
$this.hide(); //hides the element.
```

Comment: @TNguyen. The term cache is a tidbit wrong (at least in my opinion). It will save a reference to the object. That will act as a middleman, removing the need to search the DOM each time you want to access the element. When i'm thnking of cache i'm thinking storage. But i guess saying that you "cache the element" isn't plain wrong, it's just not my way to describe it.